# Captcha not Appearing or Malfunctioning on one system and working on the other

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, recaptcha, captcha

I wrote a Python script for mass commenting on a certain website.It works perfectly on my computer but when my friend tried running it on his then a Captcha would appear on the login page where as on running it on my machine no captcha appears.I tried resetting the caches,cookies but still no captcha. Tried resetting the browser settings but still no luck and on the other system the captcha always appears.If you could list down the reasons of why this happening that would be great.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

His IP is probably flagged. Also recaptcha will automatically throw a captcha if an outdated or odd user agent is detected.